# edit cell error with gspreadr

Tags: r, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have been tinkering with gspreadr and have stumbled on an error message whenever I try to edit cells. Even when I try to create a new worksheet using the examples from the gspreadr github, I still get the same error.

here is the example code from gspreadr

```
yo <- new_ss("yo")
yo <- edit_cells(yo, input = head(iris), header = TRUE, trim = TRUE)
get_via_csv(yo)
```

the error comes from

https://github.com/jennybc/gspreadr/blob/master/R/utils.R

line 74

I was wondering if maybe this is because google has updated spreadsheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't share your error message, but I suspect the problem has been resolved. Previously there was an undeclared dependency on the development version of the stringr package (vs. the CRAN version), which has since been eliminated. Please try re-installing the package.

BTW the package has been renamed from gspreadr to googlesheets.

https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

Comment: Yes thank you, updating to googlsheets solved both this question and an earlier question you answered.